Consolidating JOIN match results as opposed to taking "last matched" only
Using jq I am executing this query
{places: [JOIN(INDEX(.thingGroups[]; .thingGroup); .places[]; .thingGroup[] // empty; add)]}
against this data
{
    "places": [
        {
            "location": "wwc1",
            "someotherdata": "asdf"
        },
        {
            "location": "wwc2",
            "thingGroup": [
                "bs-2"
            ]
        },
        {
            "location": "wwc3",
            "thingGroup": [
                "bs-3",
                "rs"
            ]
        },
        {
            "location": "wwc4",
            "thingGroup": [
                "bs-4",
                "rs"
            ]
        },
        {
            "location": "wwp1",
            "thingGroup": [
                "refdoc-bs"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "thingGroups": [
        {
            "thingGroup": "bs-1",
            "things": [
                "bp",
                "ci",
                "cc"
            ]
        },
        {
            "thingGroup": "bs-2",
            "things": [
                "ems",
                "erec",
                "exs"
            ]
        },
        {
            "thingGroup": "bs-3",
            "things": [
                "ci",
                "co",
                "dq"
            ]
        },
        {
            "thingGroup": "bs-4",
            "things": [
                "ems",
                "erec",
                "home"
            ]
        },
        {
            "thingGroup": "rs",
            "things": [
                "cust"
            ]
        },
        {
            "thingGroup": "refdoc-bs",
            "things": [
                "refdoc"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "fStuff": [
        "this",
        "is",
        "extra"
    ]
}

The issue is locations "wwc3" and "wwc4" are only being matched to thingGroup "rs". The desired output is to have the things array generated for these two locations be a combination of all thingGroups that match, not just the last one. Those elements should look like this:
{
    "location": "wwc3",
    "thingGroup": [
        "bs-3",
        "rs"
    ],
    "things": [
        "ci",
        "co",
        "dq",
        "cust"
    ]
}, 
{
    "location": "wwc4",
    "thingGroup": [
        "bs-4",
        "rs"
    ],
    "things": [
        "ems",
        "erec",
        "home",
        "cust"
    ]
}

I have tried using the in() and has() functions to no avail. I feel I am close but missing something obvious.  Any help is appreciated.
ADDENDUM: the possibility of a place with no thingGroup (see wwc1) is possible.  These would need to simply be output as is.  Likewise, extraneous objects (see fStuff) could be present and should be untouched/preserved.  Apologies for the initial mock-up not capturing these scenarios.
Demo

With your attempt, add simply flat-merges all the matches, and since .things is an array, latter occurrences just overwrite the clashing former ones. Replace it with a custom merge, that takes the streamed first item (from .places), and adds to it a .things array containing the concatenated items from the other matching items (those from .thingGroups):
{places: [JOIN(INDEX(.thingGroups[]; .thingGroup); .places[]; .thingGroup[];
  first + {things: [.[1:][].things[]]}
)]}

Demo
Alternatively, perform the whole mapping yourself directly:
INDEX(.thingGroups[]; .thingGroup) as $thingGroups
| {places: [.places[] | .things = [$thingGroups[.thingGroup[]].things[]]]}

Demo
Output:
{
  "places": [
    {
      "location": "wwc1",
      "thingGroup": [
        "bs-1"
      ],
      "things": [
        "bp",
        "ci",
        "cc"
      ]
    },
    {
      "location": "wwc2",
      "thingGroup": [
        "bs-2"
      ],
      "things": [
        "ems",
        "erec",
        "exs"
      ]
    },
    {
      "location": "wwc3",
      "thingGroup": [
        "bs-3",
        "rs"
      ],
      "things": [
        "ci",
        "co",
        "dq",
        "cust"
      ]
    },
    {
      "location": "wwc4",
      "thingGroup": [
        "bs-4",
        "rs"
      ],
      "things": [
        "ems",
        "erec",
        "home",
        "cust"
      ]
    },
    {
      "location": "wwp1",
      "thingGroup": [
        "refdoc-bs"
      ],
      "things": [
        "refdoc"
      ]
    }
  ]
}



ADDENDUM: the possibility of a place with no thingGroup (see wwc1) is possible.  These would need to simply be output as is.  Likewise, extraneous objects (see fStuff) could be present and should be untouched/preserved.

Regarding wwc1, as you've figured out, changing .thingGroup[] to .thingGroup[]? will (in both approaches) treat items in .place with no .thingGroup array present as if it had produced a key of null, for which the index lookup then fails. The .things array (then empty) is still produced due to how it is constructed. To remedy this, either update the merging with an appropriate condition using if or select, or just delete the key afterwards if the array happens to be empty (but take into account that there may be other causes for it to come out empty).
As for fStuff, the {places: […]} construct produces an object containing only the .places key. To retain the other keys, use .places = […] instead to just replace the old key with a newly generated one. Note that in this case, you'd have to explicitly delete the .thingGroups key if it should not be also considered an "extraneous object" to be preserved.
.places = [JOIN(INDEX(.thingGroups[]; .thingGroup); .places[]; .thingGroup[]?;
  first + if has(1) then {things: [.[1:][].things[]]} else {} end
)] | del(.thingGroups)

Demo
INDEX(.thingGroups[]; .thingGroup) as $thingGroups
| .places |= map(select(.thingGroup).things = [$thingGroups[.thingGroup[]?].things[]])
| del(.thingGroups)

Demo
Output:
{
  "places": [
    {
      "location": "wwc1",
      "someotherdata": "asdf"
    },
    {
      "location": "wwc2",
      "thingGroup": [
        "bs-2"
      ],
      "things": [
        "ems",
        "erec",
        "exs"
      ]
    },
    {
      "location": "wwc3",
      "thingGroup": [
        "bs-3",
        "rs"
      ],
      "things": [
        "ci",
        "co",
        "dq",
        "cust"
      ]
    },
    {
      "location": "wwc4",
      "thingGroup": [
        "bs-4",
        "rs"
      ],
      "things": [
        "ems",
        "erec",
        "home",
        "cust"
      ]
    },
    {
      "location": "wwp1",
      "thingGroup": [
        "refdoc-bs"
      ],
      "things": [
        "refdoc"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "fStuff": [
    "this",
    "is",
    "extra"
  ]
}


How would I tweak this if not all places had a thingGroup element?

Answering my own follow-up above:  adding a ? in the right place seems to do the trick.
e.g. $thingGroups[.thingGroup[]?
With this solution it should be noted places having no thingGroup association will have empty things added to them, which may or may not be desirable.

@Jim You should have reflected this in your sample data. You can always filter a stream by using select as, for example, with .places[] | select(has("thingGroup"))

Agreed.  I was more focused on relaying the current issue via mock data than ensuring said data reflected an accurate real-world state.  I'll modify my question so this and other factors are present.  Thanks.
